# Write a test method to determine, if code have risk of getting null reference exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception, nullreferenceexception

I am trying to write a generic test method in C#, which will tell me if, a target method have risk of getting null reference exception.

I want to run this method against all the functions in the class and would like to determine which methods have risk of getting a null reference exception.

Something Like below,

```
[TestMethod]
Public Void TestReferenceVulnarability()
{
    try
    {
        MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
        //Do something
        target = _myClass.DoSomething();
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do something here
    }
}
```

The manual process we use to determine if a code have vulnerability of null refrence exeption. I want to automate this.

While writing code, we carefully look at objects if, there is a risk of getting null reference exception. If so, We add null checks to cover that risk.
However, in runtime, we still sometimes get null refrence exeption, as manual checking overlooked the risk.

How can I write test method/functionality, which will automate this process, and tell me if a function have risk of getting null reference exception.

Comment: ...and what is your question?

Comment: How can I write such test method? Which will predict if a target method have risk of getting null reference exception.

Comment: That wouldn't be a TestMethod but a code analyzer.

Comment: i dont think it would be that simple. do you want to analyze the code? probably resharper can do that but im not sure.

Comment: Unit tests are not for checking the vulnerabilities in the code. They are to test the functionality. That is the algorithm working as it should. Unit test is not the way to go for your requirement.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary Even with resharper installed it [doesn't highlight](http://imgur.com/VUOYLAI) things like this - there's the potential for `b` to be `null`, but it doesn't tell you about it

Comment: Potentially ANY method has a risk to return an NRE, so what shell such a method in particular do? Execute the method and print if an exception has been thrown? You´ll need no Unit-Test for this.

Comment: The manual process we use to determine if a code have vulnerability of null refrence exeption, by looking at the code. I want to automate this.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably recommend you restructure your test.
In unit testing, try and catches are not needed as much, as the exception itself will raise the failure. If you handle the exception, you risk suppressing failing tests.

```
        [TestMethod]
        Public Void TestReferenceVulnarability()
        {
            MyClass _myClass = new MyClass();
            //Do something
            Assert.NotNull(myClass.DoSomething);
        }

public class MyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
```

From the tests point of view, all it can do is exercise the code paths within the method being targeted based on inputs into the method.
So you should target common areas of failure, think about edge cases etc.
Look at your requirements.

At the moment, your 'DoSomething' method accepts no arguments, which reduces your ability to test it.

If the method is required to accept numbers between 100 and 500, then first test that those values work, then add more tests to verify the negative scenarios. When it comes to unit testing, there is no such thing as  'too many tests', as long as you keep unit tests clean and concise.

```
        [TestMethod]
        Public Void TestReferenceFor100()
        {
            //Eg: if an invalid number returns null, then we test valid numbers
           MyClass class = new MyClass();
           Assert.NotNull(class.DoSomething(100));
        }

        [TestMethod]
        Public Void TestReferenceFor500()
        {
            //Eg: if an invalid number returns null, then we test valid numbers
           MyClass class = new MyClass();
           Assert.NotNull(class.DoSomething(500));
        }
            [TestMethod]
        Public Void TestReferenceFor99()
        {
            //Eg: Now test some negative edge cases
           MyClass class = new MyClass();
           Assert.IsNull(class.DoSomething(99));
        }
                [TestMethod]
        Public Void TestReferenceFor501()
        {
            //Eg: Now test some negative edge cases
           MyClass class = new MyClass();
           Assert.IsNull(class.DoSomething(501));
        }
public class MyClass
    {
        public void DoSomething(int i)
        {
            // Do something here
        }
    }
```

So bringing this back to the original question.
In order to test the potential of getting Null Reference from that method, you need to give the test the ability to provide new inputs to the method.
Then you need to create a test for each possible input you can provide to the method.
If you have access to Reflector (.Net VS Extension), then it can identify at code time, if the code has potential for Null reference 
(it will even highlight it and offer to fix it for you.)

Comment: There's also a way to set a test attribute [ExpectsException(NullReferenceException)] or something similar to that syntax.

Comment: This is true, so you could keep the test content static, but just change the attributes for the test. That being said, it would be 6 of 1, half a dozen of the other. As it would require just as much typing.

Answer (score -1):

You would need to use reflection, to get all the public methods in the class.
Invoke them, and assert that it doest not throw a null ref

`Assert.That(Assert.DoesNotThrow(method.Invoke());` or be more explicit about it and wrap it into a try catch block, and check if the exception was NOT nullRef

Comment: I think that this will work if there is a throw keyword in the function. Because any function having a method call can throw NRE!!